# Estimating number of events per patient on right-censored data?

Tags: survival

Scenario:

- A single patient can experience multiple events at different times
- Patients have a randomization date
- Patients are right censored at last follow-up

Ultimate goal: Estimate the average number of events-per-patient in this population as a function of time.

If I was only interested in the first event or a patient could only experience one event, 1 - Kaplan-Meier estimate, would be an appropriate measure. However, this wouldn't work for multiple events, because the KM method doesn't recognize individual patients.